# Taking Pictures Every 200 milliseconds In Flutter on iOS (Burst Mode)

Tags: flutter

I tried using the Camera Plugin to perform Burst mode. But it seems quite impossible to take pictures every 0.2 seconds. Because it takes almost 1 second for 1 picture

Could anyone please guide on how to efficiently take multiple photos in the shortest time possible?

Comment: Did you use [takePicture](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraController/takePicture.html) method from [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin?

Comment: Is there any limit on photos to be taken or it depends on how long the user holds the capture button?

Comment: @AlannMaulana Yes

Comment: @KaushikChandru I need to get 10 pictures within 2 seconds

Answer (score 2):

I've been messing around with the Camera Plugin, and I don't have good news..

On Android, the plugin is calling a MethodChannel triggering the native code  of the library, capturing a Photo.
To capture the photo, the following is done :

1. The "take a picture" action is triggered
2. The method allowing to take a picture is locked
3. A file *.jpg is created in the Cache.
4. The focus is done.
5. The preview is stabilized to have a still image
6. The picture is taken and saved in the cache
7. The method allowing to take a picture is unlocked.

Problem is, steps 3 to 6 can take a lot of time...
Stabilizing the image, having the right focus and writing on the phone's memory are expensive actions which take time.

You can either try your luck by asking for an evolution of the Camera Plugin, or try another plugin like [CameraAwesome](https://pub.dev/packages/camerawesome) which should work (in theory, I've only been reading the code of the lib, I didn't try it myself)

Comment: what about the iOS implementation? Is it more efficient?

Comment: The same logic was implemented on iOS side indeed

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but it's not burst mode but more of a fake burst mode. Show the ui like camera but when the user holds the capture button record a video for 2 seconds. Then using a package like [export video frame](https://pub.dev/packages/export_video_frame) export the video to an album and save it to the device. This method will work even on devices that doesn't support burst mode

Comment: This i a great work around but video frames are usually blurred. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is to call click->method channel->native code->Action * 10 in very short duration.
@Kaushik's Answer might be a solution but it will not look seamless.

I would suggest write a method in native code to
(# take picture # save it in memory ) * 10
# create a file
# write those pictures from memory into a file
# return the path
then invoke this method using channel and access the file using path.